# Fundemental theorem of calculus when the function also depends on the limit

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have a pretty simple calculus question that I can't quite figure out. Mainly, I want to do

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t G(\tau,t) d\tau
$$

If $G$ did not depend on $t$, then it's just fundamental theorem of calculus. Also, it's not hard to compute $G'(\tau,t)$, but I'm not sure how to do that before integrating.

I had a guess, which I'm sure is wrong, of
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t G(\tau,t) d\tau = (G(t,t)-G(t,0))G'(t,t)
$$
but I feel like it's not taking into account the $G'(t,\tau)$ that should be happening somewhere.

Any clarification / references would be appreciated!

Comment: This is simply Leibniz integral rule. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: perfect thank you. Glad to know it was a simple fix!